# How may I upload live feed onto my application? Where can I get currency feeds for all currencies?

Tags: objective-c, asp-classic, vbscript

Can somebody help me with this? How may I upload live feed onto my application? Where can I get currency feeds for all currencies?

Comment: Do you want to solve it in VB or ObjC? Very different languages, and the targeting platforms are _almost_ mutually exclusive (Windows vs Macs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free feeds from geoplugin, but I think it only provides current rate exchanges and does not allow you to query for past dates.

http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/currency

Answer (score 0):

Xe.com have a data feed service which is licenced.

http://www.xe.com/dfs/?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=239x61&utm_content=NoGeo&utm_campaign=DFS_tvglobal_239x61

Answer (score 0):

Had a look around as I there are paid ones, but it depends if you want to pay for the feed or if you want a daily updated one or an hourly one ... or completely live.

I've found - http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml and http://forexfeed.net/forex-data-services

Which might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some data feed providers that have free plans. I am using https://www.currencydatafeed.com, who provide a free plan with 1 minute updates and 30 minutes delay.

If you are looking for a real-time feed, they also provide the cheapest on the net.